# Optimisation under constraint of Wasserstein distance

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $\mathcal P_n = \{P \in  \mathbb R^n_{\geq 0}: P^T \mathbb I = 1 \}$, where $\mathbb I = (1,...,1)^T \in \mathbb R^n$ and $f: \mathcal P_n \to \mathbb R$ a convex and differentiable function (or it can be as smooth as you like). Given $Q \in \mathcal P_n$ and the parameter $c > 0$, I'm interested in the following problem:
\begin{align*}
    \min_{P \in \mathcal P_n} \;\; & f(P) \\
    \text{s.t.} \;\;
        & W_p(P,Q) \leq c
\end{align*}

Here I consider the following discrete transport:
$$W_p(P,Q) = \min_{\pi \in \Pi(P,Q)} \langle D,\pi \rangle$$
where:

- $\Pi(P,Q) = \{ \pi \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}_{\geq 0}: \pi \mathbb I = P, \pi^T \mathbb I = Q \}$.
- $D \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}_{\geq 0}$ with $D_{ij} = |i-j|^p$, for $p \in [1, \infty]$.

I have $3$ questions:

- Are there any efficient numerical methods to solve this problem?
- Should it be easier/more difficult (numerically) for the different values of $p$?
- If, instead, we use the discrete regularised transport:
  $$W_p^{\epsilon}(P,Q) = \min_{\pi \in \Pi(P,Q)} \langle D,\pi \rangle - \epsilon H(\pi)$$
  where $H(\pi) = - \sum_{i,j} \pi_{ij} (\ln(\pi_{ij} - 1))$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Regarding this regularised optimisation problem,

  - Is it easier/more difficult (numerically) than the original problem?
  - If $\epsilon \to 0$, does its optimal solution converge to that of the original problem?

Comment: @MichaelGrant: you are correct, I've edited the question. The support should be the same.

Comment: @MichaelGrant How come is it not convex? It is a simplex.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Why is it not convex? If $P,Q \in \mathcal P_n$, let $t \in [0,1]$, we need to show that $tP + (1-t)Q \in \mathcal P_n$. But $tP + (1-t)Q = \sum (t p_i + (1-t)q_i) \delta_{x_i}$ and $\sum (t p_i + (1-t)q_i) = 1$, so $tP + (1-t)Q \in \mathcal P_n$.

Comment: Hey folks, I apologize. I misread the text and thought there was effectively a cardinality constraint in there.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: I have reformulated the problem, hopefully it's more clear. I would love to hear you opinions or comments on this problem.